# React PWA not working on production on nginx server

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, progressive-web-apps, nginx-config

Getting following error when deploying React app with service worker on nginx server with docker, the error cause service worker to be `status: redundant`

[image]

Here is my docker config

```
ARG ENV
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY . .
RUN ls -la
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build:$ENV
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
EXPOSE 80
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and nginx default.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }

  location /healthz {
    access_log off;
    return 200 "healthy\n";
  }

  error_page 404 /index.html;
  location = /index.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    internal;
  }
  
}
```

App runs fine when running ./build version locally with servo but only one deployment it shows above error and service worker no longer works.